# Recipient Activity tab under email template item does not track unsubscribe contact data

Tags: exm, tracking

We are unsubscribing contact through client api and using custom url in email campaign message and calling custom method, we are using the below code :

```
 _clientApiService.UpdateListSubscription(new UpdateListSubscriptionMessage()
{
  ListSubscribeOperation = ListSubscribeOperation.Unsubscribe,
  ContactIdentifier = contactIdentifiers,
  MessageId = messageID
});
```

Above code is working fine and unsubscribed contact in contact list. However, it does not track unsubscribe contact data in EXM email campaign template item when we check through exm.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation has some useful details on the Unsubscribe process. Please find the link below :

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/email-marketing.html#unsubscribing-from-campaigns_body

> The contact unsubscribes from a campaign by clicking an unsubscribe
> link in an email. This opens a tracking page on the CD role where an
> EXM unsubscribe handler does three things:
>
> It creates an interaction with an Unsubscribe page event in the
> Session State database.
>
> It stores an Unsubscribe message on the Message Bus.
>
> It redirects the contact to a user-friendly unsubscribe page.
>
> When the contact's session ends, the CD role passes the interaction
> with the Unsubscribe page event to the xConnect Collection Search role
> that stores it in the xDB Collection database. Sitecore uses this
> information for analytics and reporting purposes.

Please check this link - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/the-unsubscribe-options.html

You can check the Unsubcribe.aspx file as mentioned in the link to see how you can ensure this.

> When you use the default email campaign templates in EXM, the email
> messages you send contain two links that allow recipients to
> unsubscribe from future email campaigns - Unsubscribe & Unsubscribe
> from all
>
> **The Unsubcribe.aspx and the UnsubscribeFromAll.aspx files** do the following:
>
> Use the ExmContext to validate that the request is valid, for example,
> that the request has a contact ID and a message ID.
>
> Register the Unsubscribe from email page event

Comment: We are using custom link in email message instead of  `/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx` link. With custom link we are calling the code. Is it possible to track unsubscribe contact data through code?